# About dense subspaces in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I have the following problem:

Let $E$ a Banach space and $X_1,X_2$ dense subspaces. Is $X_1\cap X_2$ dense in $X$? What is the answer if $X_1,X_2$ has codimension 1?

I don't know how to start. If anyone can give me a hint it will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are dense, $X_1 \cap X_2$ need not be dense, in fact it might be just $\{0\}$.  Consider any infinite-dimensional separable Banach space $E$.  Start with a dense countable set $\{w_1, w_2, \ldots\}$.  Inductively choose two sequences $x_j$ and $y_j$ such that $\|x_j - w_j\| < 1/j$ and $\|y_j - w_j\| < 1/j$ and $\{x_1, y_1, \ldots, x_j, y_j\}$ is linearly independent.  Let $X_1$ be the linear span of the $x_j$ and $X_2$ the linear span of the $y_j$.  Then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are dense in $E$ and $X_1 \cap X_2 = \{0\}$.

Comment: One very explicit example from real analysis:

Let $X = L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Let $X_1$ be the subset of simple functions. Let $X_2$ be the subset of smooth functions.

Comment: @WillieWong. Yes. And another example: Let $E=C[0,1],$ the set of continuous $ f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R, $ with $\|f-g\|=\max_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|. $ Let $X_1$ be the set of differentiable $f \in E$ and let $X_2$ be the set of piece-wise linear $ f \in E.$ Then $X_1\cap X_2$ is the set of linear members of $E,$ which has dimension $2,$ although $E$ is infinite-dimensional.